# Jquery Multiple "this"

Tags: jquery, append, this

I have this function and the second `this` needs to refer not to the line before it but to the first line of the function:

```
$('.externallink').each(function() {
    var $externallink = $(this).html();
    if ($externallink.length > 0) {
        $(this).closest('tr').children('.filter').append('<p> test</p>');
    }
});
```

So the first `(this).html()` refers to the `('.externallink').each(function()`.

The second `(this).closest('tr')` I want to also refer to the first `('.externallink').each(function()`, but I have a feeling it's referring to the `($externallink.length > 0)` that is right above it.

There are multiple rows in this table so I need to make sure that `('.filter')` classes that this is being appended to is only the one that's in the same row as the `.externallink` in the question.

---

```
<tr>
   <td style="width: 35%">
      <a class="filter" href="#">March</a>
   </td>
   <td class="year" style="width: 20%">2010</td>
   <td class="externallink" style="display:none">http://www.google.com/</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `this` in the second line still refers to the .externallink. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There's no error, it just doesn't do anything. However, if I change the last line to just $('.filter').append('<p> test</p>'); then the paragraph will be appended to every single filter class on the page.

Comment: In that case there is something wrong in the way you are trying to navigate to .filter. Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @Cybernate: The OP already gets notified when an answer is submitted.

Comment: @genesis: The mistakes are the reason that he's asking the question. His code is broken. That's why we're all here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is perfectly fine and referring to .externallink.

I don't think there is any function called `child` in jQuery, use `children` instead

Change your code to:

```
$('.externallink').each(function() {
    var $externallink = $(this).html();
        if ($externallink.length > 0) {
            //$(this).closest('tr').children('.filter').append('<p> test</p>');
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.filter').append('<p> test</p>');

        }
    });
```

If you can post HTML the navigation to .filter can be validated as well.

Comment: @Cybernate: No; look at the HTML again.

Comment: @Tomalak: My bad.. forgot children goes only one level.

Comment: @kramden88: Tomalak's answer should be marked as answer because he gave the best answer first. Please reconsider

Answer (score 2):

In this case you are safe.  Within a given function call the value of `this` will not be changed.  In this scenario there is only a single function in which you are using `this`: the callback to `each`.  Hence `this` refers to the same DOM element throughout the function and there is no need to cache / save it

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `$(this)` is fine. `this` will not change inside a function scope. You might be better off caching it, but that's a separate discussion and not related to solving your problem.

---

There is no function `child`, and even [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) doesn't do what you appear to want:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   .children() method allows us to search through the **immediate**
>   children of these elements in the DOM tr

Your object with class `.filter` is not an immediate child of the `tr`.

Just use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead, or its shorthand equivalent:

```
$('.externallink').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $externallink = $this.html();
    if ($externallink.length > 0) {
        $('.filter', $this.closest('tr')).append('<p> test</p>'); // <---
    }
});
```

(Notice that I also chose to apply the aforementioned optimisation, by caching `$(this)`.)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! Out of curiosity, what would the longhand equivalent be?

Comment: @kramden88: `$this.closest('tr').find('.filter').append(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$(this)` are referencing the same `this` which will be the DOM element with the CSS class `externallink` in the current `each()` iteration.

You could store `$(this)` in a variable so you don't call the `$()` function twice on it (it's a 2 second optimization but the impact will be pretty negligible as the function exits very early when dealing with a DOM element. Do whichever is easier to read for you and your team).